# how to generate a distribution / testflight build with a developer only privilege?

Tags: ios

I am asked to generate a testflight build  for my iOS (Xamarin) project. I know that the testflight option is not enabled for a member account with developer privilege. I requested for admin privilege, but was denied.

I wonder if the current admin provides me a distribution provisioning profile, will i be able to generate an distribution ipa and upload to testflight ? Please suggest me the work wround in this siituation

tx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can upload a build with the developer role but you will either need the [App Manager](https://developer.apple.com/support/roles/) role or someone with that role will need to manage TestFlight for your build on your behalf.

Comment: do you have some steps pls ? when I select auto provisioning, i do not see option, how to upload the build !

Comment: Archive and then upload that build from the organiser window